# What does the dd command do?

Tags: linux, usb-flash-drive, dd, copy

If I make a copy with the "dd" command from a block device say 8 GB to a 16 GB block device, the content of the first device is copied to the second device until it is full? (that is, until the 16gb is filled, which would be 2 times) or only the content of the first device is copied to the second device 1 time?

Does the same thing happen if I copy a 6GB .iso image to an 8GB device? That is, in this case, it will copy the entire .iso file once, and then only copy 2GB of that file?

If true, why don't we usually specify the `bs` and `count` options when creating a copy of a device like this: `sudo dd if=/dev/sdc of=image.iso`? Logically, it should keep copying to infinity, however it doesn't, and creates a file the exact size of the USB stick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dd` will keep copying until it meets one of three conditions

1. it receives an error on reading - the source device has no more blocks to read
2. it receives an error on writing - the destination device has no more blocks to be written
3. it reaches the count of `count` blocks of block size `bs`

The first two conditions take precedence over the third. If either of those are met first then it will simply exit.

So:

1. If you have a 6GB source and copy it to an 8GB destination then it will copy 6GB of data and stop.
2. If you have a 16GB source and an 8GB destination then it will copy 8GB of data and then stop.
3. If you tell it to copy 4,096,000 blocks of 1024 bytes then it will copy 4GB of data, unless it meets the end of either the source or destination devices in which case it will copy only the `size` of the source or destination.

Comment: 0. SIGKILL, SIGTERM, SIGINT, …

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski admittedly anything specifically interrupting it, such as another program or the user, will take precedence over the "normal" conditions... but then the same could be said of a power cut

Comment: OK, `dd` has no means to survive a power cut or SIGKILL, so mentioning them is indeed stating the obvious. But it *could* ignore SITGERM or SIGINT. Not ignoring them and exiting is what the designer(s) chose. Similarly exiting "when it reaches the count of `count` blocks of block size `bs`" was a design decision. For comparison: the default action for SIGUSR1 is to terminate, but GNU `dd` does something else.

Comment: @Mokubai But if the copy process stops when there are no more blocks to be read, why do you usually set the `bs=512` and `count=1` options when recovering an MBR backup like so: `sudo dd if=mbr.img of=/dev/sda bs=512 count=1`

Comment: @yellowdog if *all* you are doing is trying to back up a specific amount of data, for example the bootsector at the start of a disk, then you would use `bs=512` and `count=1` to cover your ass. If you accidentally gave the wrong filename then the worst you've done is guaranteed that you only overwrite the first block of the disk rather than some random amount of blocks. It's safer, particularly if you have a full disk image that you only want one block from.

Comment: @yellowdog it is defensive and paranoid, a good way to be when dealing with your critical data. At worst you've overwritten the bootsector and have other ways to boot and try again. Without those options if you accidentally give the wrong filename you have potentially lost some random amount of possibly critical data you won't be able to recover.

Comment: @yellowdog conversely using those options by default makes it easy to go the other way. You simply swap the source and destination and all you copy is your intended bootsector block to a file and not the whole disk, then you just swap them back to write it back or change where you go to. Otherwise you would have to figure out how to truncate a huge file down to the 512 bytes you actually want. Being clear and specific can make your life easier.

Comment: @Mokubai I am a little confused.
For example, in the case of wanting to make a bootable usb from a debian11 `.iso` image: `dd if=debian11.iso of=/dev/sdc`
Why are the `bs` and `count` options not usually specified in these cases? If it was an 8 GB usb and the image is 4 GB, would it copy it twice? or will it stop when 4 GB has been copied?

Comment: Why do you think it *should* copy twice? It will continue to copy until it reaches the end of the input **or** output, **whichever one is smaller**. It has no reason to go back to the start.

Comment: @Mokubai OK, thanks for the detailed answers!